# How to use a pointer to character within a c structure?

Tags: c, struct, char, malloc

It is possible to declare a string of the required size using `char name[size]`, however if I want to use `char *name`, how will I specify the size that I require using `malloc()`?

I found out that I cannot use `char *name = malloc(5*1);` within the structure declaration.

I have tried using

```
struct data
{
    int age;
    char *name;
};
```

On running this code and entering the string I encountered Segmentation fault.
How must I specify the size?

Comment: You need to separetly `malloc` the memory for `name` after you alocated the `struct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say you create a variable `a` of the type `struct data`

```
struct data a;
```

Now allocate memory to the name member of `a` i.e,

```
a.name = malloc(size_of_name + 1); //+1 for '\0' character at the end
```

Now you can use `a.name` to store and use the string

Don't forget to free the allocated data before terminating the program. for this use `free(a.name)`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to *specify the size of the pointer*, you need to make the pointer to point to a valid memory, that's all. Moreover, it not *necessary* to use `malloc()`. You can either

- allocate memory to the pointer via allocator functions, `malloc()` or family
- make the pointer point to the address of any other `char` variable (or array)

To elaborate, you create a variable `var` of type `struct data`, and then, make `var->name` point to a valid chunk of memory.

That said, to use `malloc()` for allocating required size of memory, you need to supply the required size as the argument to `malloc()` (in bytes).

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate the memory like:

```
data* r = malloc(sizeof(data));
r->name= malloc(20);
```

assuming the name can hold 20 chars

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to supply a way to initialize your structure. For example:

```
void init_data (struct data *p_data) {
  if (p_data)
    p_data->name = malloc(STR_LEN);
}
```

And you should couple that with a function to free the memory:

```
void release_data (struct data *p_data) {
  if (p_data)
    free(p_data->name);
}
```

It would than be called whenever you want to use your structure.

```
struct data d;
init_data(&d);
/* use d */
release_data(&d);
```